# Is there a list of free available robot models for gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, robot-model, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wanted to know if there is a list of free available robots to play with in gazebo; such as [turtlebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator), [PR2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator),  [erratic-robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/TeleopErraticSimulation)?

Maybe there are some models for the Pioneer, Care-O-bot, Roomba, Peoplebot, Nao, Aibo, Kephera, etc.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12205/is-there-a-list-of-free-available-robot-models-for-gazebo?/) by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2011-12-04

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though not Gazebo specific, [this page](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Examples)  has a list of many of the models that are available.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2011-12-06**:
I think I also think that a better search at the Player Project page will add some models to this list.

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2011-12-06**:
Thanks for your help! this list is very helpful & ilustrative. I also found a model for the Youbot Arm:http://youbot-store.com/simulation/12/software.aspx

**Comment by [mohit_rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/28477/mohit_rai/) on 2016-11-10**:
hey can't I download the models from models.gazebosim.org, so that gazebo doesn't have to look for these models online or dependent on the internet connection, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a [pioneer2dx world file](http://ubuntuone.com/5pWIiUyo1mhrY2PHP4I86C), and some tips to use it in [gazebo](http://mobotica.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-gazebo.html).

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-06**:
@marcobecerrap : You are welcome !

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2011-12-06**:
Thanks for your help!